# Material Design android studio

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design, android-recyclerview

Is it possible to use `CardView` with `RecyclerView` and `NavigationDrawer` all together? If it is possible, someone suggest me any example based on it, and if it is not possible, then pls give me an answer explaining why it is not possible.

For example, if in this sample code given in this url:  http://javatechig.com/android/android-recyclerview-example, 
I want to add a `DrawerLayout` simultaneously with `RecyclerView` and `CardView`, then is it possible or not ?????

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look here http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html.. And chris banes has shown a wonderful example of its application take a look here https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: Thank you for the example but just have query is it possible to collabrate all 3 views without using collapsingtoolbarlayout as used in example 
like its possible to collabrate recycleview and cardview at a time in the same manner recycleview+cardview+navigationdrawer at a time

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible?

Yes, it is certainly possible to use cardview with recycleview and navigationdrawer.

You can view the following:

- [Getting Started With RecyclerView and CardView on Android](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465)
- [Material Navigation Drawer with recycle view and Card view](http://codedrops.xyz/374440)
- [RecyclerView in Material Design](http://themasterworld.com/recyclerview-in-material-design/)

If you want a video, I would recommend watching:

- [Android Material Design Tutorial -- Slidnerd](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD)

He really explains it very well in this series. You can also find many others on YouTube.

Comment: Thanks for URL but i already tried recycle with cardview or recycle with navigation drawer but dont get all 3 together and that video is not in working :)

Comment: how can that video not work , you are also from mumbai and vivz too.